# Enforce HTTPS across thousands of 301 RewriteRule entries

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

community.  I'm migrating an ancient ColdFusion site (seriously), and we have literally thousands of 301 redirects from old versions of pages like

```
index.cfm?id=1&this=that
```

to more reasonable counterparts like

```
/what-this-page-really-is
```

Google says to list them out one by one, so that's what I'm doing.  However, on ALL of these redirects we also want to enforce HTTPS.  What we have now is this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thing.cfm$ /thing/? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blah.cfm$ /awesome-sauce/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

It works fine, but Google complains that it's technically two redirects for these old links.  A possible solution would be to exclude *.cfm files from the HTTPS redirect and explicitly make every single *.cfm redirect go to the HTTPS version of the page, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)cfm$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thing.cfm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/thing/? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blah.cfm$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/awesome-sauce/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

But over thousands of lines, that's a lot of extra characters in an .htaccess file.  I know this is better in apache config, but I don't have that option right now.

My question: is there a way to set a flag that's going to apply the HTTPS parameter to ALL of the subsequent *.cfm 301 redirects?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than enforcing `https://` in each 301 handler you can move your `http->https` rule at the bottom and remove `R` flag from your redirect flags so that Google (or any external client) gets only one single redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^thing\.cfm$ /thing/? [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blah\.cfm$ /awesome-sauce/? [L,NC]

# all other rules here but remove R=301 flag

# finally do a http->https with rewritten URI
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. It never occurred to me that I could execute another RewriteRule after the L(ast) flag.  Thank you kindly for your advice.  Not only does this solution achieve my primary goal, but I trimmed about 5% of my file size getting rid of those R=301s!